# Vuex - How to check if a module has been registered

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

When trying to unregister a module with `this.$store.unregisterModule([ModulePath, ModuleName])`, sometimes I get this warning console `[vuex] trying to unregister module 'ModulePath\ModuleName', which is not registered`

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a specific module is registered? so I can make a conditional unregistration like this:

```
if(module ModuleName is registered) {
   this.$store.unregisterModule([ModulePath, ModuleName])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by calling `store.hasModule`.
From Vuex documentation:

> Note that you may check if the module is already registered to the store or not via store.hasModule(moduleName) method.

See [Dynamic module registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration)